# What does this option at the end of NieR: Automata actually do?

Tags: nier-automata

After beating

> the credits mini-game

in NieR: Automata's last main ending, you get two options. One of these is

> to simply display a message made out of per-selected phrases to
>  display to other players going through the same mini-game,

simple enough.

But after that question, you're given a heftier question. Your pod asks if

> you would like to "save" another, random, player.
>  
>   In order to do this though, you must have all of your save data
>  erased. As I'm not yet done getting achievements or side endings,

I said no, leaving me curious as to what he meant. What exactly would have happened

> to this randomly selected player

if I had I hit yes?

> Would I get any indication of anything that happened as well, or would
>  the pod have just said 'affirmative', erased my data, and send me back
>  to the title screen?

Comment: May want to put some spoiler tags around your stuff

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ah, the big choice.

> Since the ending sequence is nigh impossible without accepting help (this is clearly intentional, as the entire point is that you can't take on enormous tasks alone), you accepted it, right? Every person that assisted you was actually someone who chose to erase all of their save data for this purpose. Had you chose to delete your save, someone out there who needed help on the ending sequence would have gotten assistance from you.

I originally declined in order to 100% the game, but as soon as I had done so, I went back and redid this sequence so that I, too,

> could erase all save data in order to assist someone else.

If you choose yes, you will actually be prompted for confirmation about 7 or 8 times before it actually happens.

> During the sequence directly following, it will show all of your data being deleted, one item at a time (though many are skipped over so this doesn't take an eternity). The very last part shows all of your save slots being erased. This means you *cannot* simply copy your save data to a second save data slot. All three are erased entirely. The only record of you having played the game and made this choice is that you will get an alternate background for the title screen. It looks like this: [image: alt bg]

Comment: Actually, I had not accepted the request for help when offered. I have some (though not a whole lot) of experience with bullet hell games, so while I probably would have not completed it without help, I certainly wasn't ready at the point when asked to do it the easy way. Or at least, I meant to hit no (I could have easily hit yes accidentally, can't say for sure). If I hit no, it gave me the help anyway.

Comment: @Tylor it will only give help if you say yes. I believe the choice defaults to yes. I tried to do it solo for about 20 minutes. Every death, it would offer me help from another player. Eventually it gets to the point where your DPS is so low and the "enemies" shoot so many bullets that it's impossible to survive. If it gave you help, it's because you selected the option. Another horrifying part is that every time you got hit after that point, someone's save was permanently deleted from the game's server.

Comment: It's worth noting that on PC at least, you can backup your save file and replace it after. In My document/my games/Nier Automata, Slot_0, Slot_1 and Slot_2 (exact name escapes me at the moment) are your 3 save slots. The 2 other files can be left as they contain the system and graphic settings (such as which title screen background you have). Doing so has no effect on game progress, endings or achievements.

Comment: @fhlamarche I believe it's possible to copy your save data to a USB for PS4, but doesn't that defeat the purpose of it all? ;)

Comment: @Vemonus "Another horrifying part is that every time you got hit after that point, someone's save was permanently deleted from the game's server. "  Huh?  What server, the game saves locally (and I doubt anyone's cloud saves get deleted)?

Comment: @Andy you have to delete all your saves to have your name appear there. By that point, the server should be the only place with your old save. If they say it's deleted, it very well could be

Comment: You say that the only record of having played is the modified title screen. Have you started a new game after deleting your save? My friend has told me that there are some differences in the game. In particular, the boss names are all written in the game's made up language instead of English.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Yep. I got ending E a second time so that I could do the DLC. The bosses' names are written in English before ending E (before routes C and D, even). 9S is able to read the machine's language, so all throughout route B, you're able to read the bosses' names in English. I distinctly remember, however, that when I was playing the game after deleting my save, I knew what all of the bosses' names were *despite* seeing alien characters when fighting them as 2B

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to downvote, but this doesn't answer the question of what it actually does. The fact that your saves are deleted is implied already. I would've expected the answer to explain if you actually helped a random person.

Comment: @Zimano I’m not sure what you want me to say to please you lol. I’m not a developer for Platinum, so I can’t tell you the *exact* nuances of this choice. It removes your save, for sure, and your name can show up for other players (it’s hard to prove this however, since it’s random and you would need a second account to be playing the same part and happen to get your name to show). You also get a nifty new startup screen. That’s what happens. *Ta-daaaa*

Answer (score 2):

The usual claim is (quoting the earlier answer) that

> > Every person that assisted you was actually someone who chose to erase all of their save data for this purpose.

The idea seems to be that there is, in effect, a counter stored on a Square Enix/Platinum server that increments every time someone

> sacrifices their save files to help someone

and decrements every time someone

> accepts the help

and when it reaches zero the second action becomes impossible.

That can't be true because of the huge difficulty gap between the incrementing and decrementing actions. (Keep in mind that the counter would be increased by a player only if they performed the incrementing action without previously performing the decrementing action.) In practice the counter would almost always be zero, but public evidence shows that it's never or almost never zero. (I'm not aware of anyone ever being unable to perform the decrementing action, but if that does happen, it's at least uncommon.)

The decrementing action displays the username of someone who allegedly performed the incrementing action. I see no reason to believe that those usernames are made up. Most likely, there's a pool of names on a server, the decrementing action randomly selects a name from the pool without removing it, and the incrementing action adds your name to the pool and removes someone else's (probably whoever's been there the longest) to prevent the size from growing without bound. That would mean that the incrementing action has no effect on the ability of others to perform the decrementing action. The only effect is that they'll see your name instead of someone else's. I think the most selfless action is to give that other person a little more time to shine.

The incrementing action also has a local effect on your machine – see the last spoiler box of the earlier answer if you want to know that effect.

Comment: What do you mean with [redacted]?

Comment: @pinckerman I wanted to avoid adding two more spoiler boxes, since they break up the flow of the text, but since it's confusing I added them.