# In NieR: Automata ending E, can you make a different choice on a subsequent playthrough?

Tags: nier-automata

At the end of Nier Automata ending E,

> when the player beats the bullet hell credit sequence, the game asks the player to sacrifice their save data to help others.

If the player chooses

> not to, can the player later return to ending E, finish it, and then sacrifice their save data?

Does it depend on whether they

> accept help in their 2nd playthrough of the credit sequence?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you are more than able to change your choice if you complete ending E again. This is what I did, as I did not have everything that I wanted to get done done when I completed ending E the first time. I deleted my save the *second* time I attained ending E.

---

I'm not 100% positive, but I am fairly certain that the bullethell sequence is nigh impossible without assistance, as after a certain point, you just start getting out-DPS'd with bullets and you can't shoot fast enough to hit any of the targets due to the sheer volume of destructible bullets coming your way.

Comment: For reference, I actually mentioned doing this in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/304049/162442) to a different question.